# Javascript/jQuery setInterval shown old value onclick re-call function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with `setInterval` function to replace text.

```js
function loadData(set){
  if(set == undefined){
    var a = "Hello";
  }
  else{
    var a = set;
  }

  setMe(a);

  function setMe(val){
    setInterval(function(){
      $(".setMe").html(val);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

loadData();

$('#clickMe').on('click', function(){
  loadData("Good");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="setMe"></div>

<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

When I try to click the button, it will change the text to be `Good`. But why the old text is still shown alternate with `Hello`? You can try on the demo.

What I want is replace the text only to be `Good`.

Comment: If you want a delay between the click and the text change try with settimeout

Comment: You're creating a second interval. The Hello one is never cleared. Here's your code, fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/odasv3qe/

Comment: I would love your answer @ChrisG, this very helpful from another best answer also. Cheers

Comment: Do you even need this to be an interval (instead of a timeout)? Are you learning JS or is there a specific purpose to this code I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `loadData` which starts the first interval setting the text to "Hello". Then when you're clicking the button, it starts another interval which sets the text to "Good". The problem is that you now have 2 intervals both setting the text value. The intervals will both keep running forever.

What you need is to use `setInterval` instead, which will only delay the change of the text value, instead of repeatedly changing it.

```js
function loadData(set){
  if(set == undefined){
    var a = "Hello";
  }
  else{
    var a = set;
  }

  setMe(a);

  function setMe(val){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(".setMe").html(val);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

loadData();

$('#clickMe').on('click', function(){
  loadData("Good");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="setMe"></div>

<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

setInterval is for running function repeatedly at regular **interval**, unless cleared.

What is happening :
You are calling your function twice and hence two intervals are running. One setting the value to `Hello` and other setting the value to `Good`.

You can replace this with setTimeout, which runs a function once, after a delay.

```js
function loadData(set){
  if(set == undefined){
    var a = "Hello";
  }
  else{
    var a = set;
  }

  setMe(a);

  function setMe(val){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(".setMe").html(val);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

loadData();

$('#clickMe').on('click', function(){
  loadData("Good");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="setMe"></div>

<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change where variable `a` is declared
And also `setInterval` is unnecessary here as you want to fire your action only once (and `setInterval` is repeated).

```
function loadData(set){
    var a;
  if(set == undefined){
    a = "Hello";
  }
  else{
    a = set;
  }

  

  function setMe(val){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(".setMe").html(val);
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  setMe(a);
}

loadData();

$('#clickMe').on('click', function(){
  loadData("Good");
});
```